# filter the "values-" folder on android studio

Tags: java, android

When you start a new android studio project, by default, you have a folder "values" and some other "values-XXXX" folders such as "values-v11" which its files are used when the API version of the device is above 11. I know that we can filter the values up to the language of the device too, by adding the directory "values-fa" . So the question is what are the other filters for values folder?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, when you are creating a new folder, you are given all of the qualifiers available on the left side of the window. In this example, I chose the `Locale` qualifier and on the right side I can choose the specific filter that I want:

[image]